# Given nested list element, find the one level back list value

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested

Say i have 
`List=[[[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']],[['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6']]],[[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']],[['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6']]]]`
i know that if i call `List[0][0]` i will get `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]`, and so on.

Is there any built-in or external python function(suppose its `func(a)`) or way to get the nested list element `a` one level back?

So if i call `func(List[0][1])` those function will return `List[0]` or when i call `func(List[1][0][1])` those function will return `List[1][0]` but if i call `func(List)` it will return `List` since it's already at the root. I've been searching for this kind of problem for hours but still couldn't find the solution.

Comment: To summarize, if you see your list as a tree, you want a function that, given a subtree, returns the parent node of that subtree? If so, the answer is no (at least with list). There are, however, many tree implementations.

Comment: yes exactly, i want to get back to the parent node of that list. So there really is not any alternative way to get this in python?

Comment: The bottom line is, List is a not a bad structure to "build" that kind of logic/abstraction on, but a list simply ISNT itself an implementation of that kind of logic/structure. You would have to use a different structure or build your own. Once you understand that, you can start looking for better alternatives to "store/represent" this relation. Be it graphs, some type of dictionary/tree structure, or so on.

Comment: @Fauzi Indeed, lists are not suited to get the "parent", because lists weren't created with that specific use case in mind (obviously). That's why you need something "more". You can either go for trees, or implement your own structure (and both can be based on lists, of course).

Comment: So that's how it is :(
Thank you guys for pointing out that list can't be seen as parent-child like node logic.

Comment: What if the same sub-list is present under more than one parent? Would it be ok to return **any** of the valid parents?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following recursive function:

```
def get_parent_list(the_elem, the_list):
    if (the_elem == the_list):
        return (True, the_elem)
    elif the_elem in the_list:
        return (True, the_list)
    else:
        for e in the_list:
            if (type(e) is list):
                (is_found, the_parent) = get_parent_list(the_elem, e)
                if (is_found):
                    return (True, the_parent)
        return (False, None)
```

**Testing it out:**

```
my_list=[[[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']],[['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6']]],
         [[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']],[['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6']]]]
```

**Test Case 1:**

```
the_child = my_list[0][1][1]
the_flag, the_parent = get_parent_list(the_child, my_list)
print (the_flag)
print (the_child)
print (the_parent)
```

**Result:**

```
True
['3', '4']
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

**Test Case 2:**

```
the_child = my_list[0][1]
the_flag, the_parent = get_parent_list(the_child, my_list)
print (the_flag)
print (the_child)
print (the_parent)
```

**Result:**

```
True
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]]
```

**Test Case 3:**

```
the_child = my_list[:]
the_flag, the_parent = get_parent_list(the_child, my_list)
print (the_flag)
print (the_child)
print (the_parent)
```

**Result:**

```
True
[[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]], [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]]]
[[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]], [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]]]
```

**Test Case 4:**

```
the_child = my_list[0][1] + ['Non-existent value']
the_flag, the_parent = get_parent_list(the_child, my_list)
print (the_flag)
print (the_child)
print (the_parent)
```

**Result:**

```
False
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], 'Non-existent value']
None
```